# How to add Stroke to Text in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, filter

I am coding in AS3 and want to add a stroke to text that I'm displaying to the screen. My current code is:

```
format = new TextFormat("BN Elements", 14, 0xEEEEEE, false, false, false, null, null, "left");
format.font = "BN Elements"
scoreText = initText(starsleftText, format, "", 160,5, 545, 61);
scoreText = "Stroke This Text";
```

As the text is dynamically generated I can't create it as a text object in the Flash IDE -  where I know to add a stroke I can use the "glow" function set to 1000% and Low quality.

I suppose my question is, how can I apply the "glow" filter effect with similar properties within AS3 directly? Or is there an alternative "stroke" function I don't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html (There's an example at the bottom of the page)

I'm not sure if they've added anything new as far as adding a real stroke, but the glow filter 'stroke' works just as well with code.

You could also create a pixel bender filter that would give you a bit more control over the effect, I can't seem to find any already written ones out there though:(

Comment: oh also, beware, if the text is selectable, using the glow filter will add a stroke to the selection as well.

Comment: I don't know that I would say "just as well"... I've spent many hours trying to get a glow-based text stroke to match a comp done in Illustrator.

Comment: I think you misread my comment, I said it will add it "as well" not "just as well".

Comment: I thank you for your feedback, but I AM acquainted with the English language. In your original answer (NOT your comment) you said "but the glow filter 'stroke' works just as well with code." To which I respond, the glow filter works, kinda, but it's nowhere near as useful as a REAL text stroking mechanism would be.

Comment: ahh. it's true then, it's not nearly as good as illustrator, but it is pretty much as good as the one rendered by flash. some combo of the two may produce a better result.

Comment: The site is down. This is why you shouldn't answer questions with links.

Comment: You're down voting a 7 year old question because the link to the language specific docs doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Flash generates its strokes from the edges of shapes. Since you are using text dynamically (not in authoring) Flash can render with either 1) device text which in drawn by the operating system, or 2) embedded text in your SWF file. In the first case, Flash doesn't (currently) have access to the edges to stroke them. In the 2nd, Flash uses a specialized sub-renderer for text that (again currently) doesn't support stroking, or for that matter, anything but solid color fills.

Short answer: stroking of text currently isn't supported in the runtime, although the glow or pixel bender approach suggested is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, though. Displaying strokes via BlurFilter works, somehow, but it is unclean and very slow, as there is so much pixel crunching done, which is absolutely not necessary.

An alternative (a fast and convenient one) is to use Pixel Benders PBJ Filters. I wrote a stroke Filter myself and it works like a charm. You can even isolate the original image if you like, so the Filter just gives you the outline, without the original image.

Parameters are:

pixel4 color

float strength

float threshold

bool isolate

http://www.file-upload.net/download-7344877/Stroke.pbj.html

Download it here and use it as you need, if you like.

If you don't know how to use Pixel Bender Filters in Flash, google is your friend. There are plenty of tutorials about it.